# How to build tree array from flat array of object with category and subCategrie properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I am trying to build tree array from flat array, each item in the flat array has two property need to be used to build the tree array, they are 1. category. 2. subCategrie which is array of string.

```
let data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Zend",
    category: "php",
    subCategory: ["framework"]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Laravel",
    category: "php",
    subCategory: ["framework"]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Vesion 5",
    category: "php",
    subCategory: ["versions"]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Angular",
    category: "frontend",
    subCategory: ["framework", "typescript"]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Aurelia",
    category: "frontend",
    subCategory: ["framework", "typescript"]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "JQuery",
    category: "frontend",
    subCategory: []
  }
];
```

It should be

```
    let tree = [
      {
        name: "php",
        children: [
          {
            name: "framework",
            children: [
              {
                id: 1,
                name: "Zend"
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                name: "Laravel"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "versions",
            children: [
              {
                id: 3,
                name: "Vesion 5"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
 // ...
    ];
```

Is there any article, link solving similar problem? 
I gave it many tries but stuck when trying to build the sub categories children.

Here's my last attempt which throws error and I know it's wrong but it's for the ones who want to see my attempts

```
const list = require('./filter.json')
let tree = {};
for (let filter of list) {
    if (tree[filter.category]) {
        tree[filter.category].push(filter);
    } else {
        tree[filter.category] = [filter];
    }
}
function buildChildren(list, subcategories, category, index) {
    let tree = {}
    for (let filter of list) {
        if (filter.subcategory.length) {
            for (let i = 0; i < filter.subcategory.length; i++) {
                let branch = list.filter(item => item.subcategory[i] === filter.subcategory[i]);
                branch.forEach(item =>{
                    if (tree[filter.subcategory[i]]){
                        tree[filter.subcategory[i]] = tree[filter.subcategory[i]].push(item)
                    }else{
                        tree[item.subcategory[i]] = [item]
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    console.log('tree ', tree);
}
```

Comment: You should provide the code of your attemp to solve the whole problem!

Comment: @SMH do you have any code attempts?

Comment: Yes I do have code attempts, here's my last attempt which throws error and it's very complicated.
I will put it the question

Answer (score 1):

The key to success here is to create an *interim* format that allows for easy lookups. Because you work with `children` arrays, you end up having to use `filter` and `find` whenever you add something new, to prevent duplicates and ensure grouping.

By working with a format based on objects and keys, it's much easier to do the grouping.

We can create the groups in a single nested loop, which means we only touch each item once for the main logic. The group has this format:

```
{ "categoryName": { "subCategoryName": [ { id, name } ] } }
```

Then, getting to the required `{ name, children }` format is a matter of one more loop over the entries of this tree. In this loop we move from `{ "categoryName": catData }` to `{ name: "categoryName", children: catData }`

Here's an example that shows the two steps separately:

```js
const data=[{id:1,name:"Zend",category:"php",subCategory:["framework"]},{id:2,name:"Laravel",category:"php",subCategory:["framework"]},{id:3,name:"Vesion 5",category:"php",subCategory:["versions"]},{id:4,name:"Angular",category:"frontend",subCategory:["framework","typescript"]},{id:5,name:"Aurelia",category:"frontend",subCategory:["framework","typescript"]},{id:6,name:"JQuery",category:"frontend",subCategory:[]}];

// { category: { subCategory: [ items ] } }
const categoryOverview = data.reduce(
  (acc, { id, name, category, subCategory }) => {
    // Create a top level group if there isn't one yet
    if (!acc[category]) acc[category] = {};
    
    subCategory.forEach(sc => { 
      // Create an array for this subCat if there isn't one yet
      acc[category][sc] = (acc[category][sc] || [])
        // and add the current item to it
        .concat({ id, name }); 
    });
    
    return acc;
  },
  {}
)

const nameChildrenMap = Object
  .entries(categoryOverview)
  // Create top level { name, children } objects
  .map(([cat, subCats]) => ({
    name: cat,
    children: Object
      .entries(subCats)
      // Create sub level { name, children } objects
      .map(([subCat, items]) => ({
        name: subCat,
        children: items
      }))
  }))

console.log(nameChildrenMap);
```

Comment: Thanks for your smart answer, However I think I couldn't explain very well how the structure of the tree should be.
Currently your solution make two sub categories on the `frontend` category 
1.framekwork
2. typescript
but I am trying to make the tree deeper so it should be something like this
frontend
        |--- frameworks
             |--- typescript
                 |--- Angular
                 |--- Aurelia

{
name: frontend,

}

Comment: Ah, you cut that part out of your desired result with the `// ...` ;) I'll see if I have time to update later today

Answer (score 1):

Heads up, For javascript I usually use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10) (usually written as `_` in code) but most of these methods should also be built in to the objects in javascript (*i.e. _.forEach = Array.forEach()*)

```
    const tree = [];
    // First Group all elements of the same category (PHP, Frontend, etc.)
    data = _.groupBy(data, 'category');
    _.forEach(data, function (categoryElements, categoryName) {
      // Each Category will have it's own subCategories that we will want to handle
      let categorySubCategories = {};
      // The categoryElements will be an array of all the objects in a given category (php / frontend / etc..)
      categoryElements.map(function (element) {
        // For each of these categoryies, we will want to grab the subcategories they belong to
        element.subCategory.map(function (subCategoryName) {
          // Check if teh category (PHP) already has already started a group of this subcategory,
          // else initialize it as an empty list
          if (!categorySubCategories[subCategoryName]) { categorySubCategories[subCategoryName] = []; }
          // Push this element into the subcategory list
          categorySubCategories[subCategoryName].push({id: element.id, name: element.name});
        });
      });
      // Create a category map, which will be a list in the format {name, children}, created from
      // our categorySubCategories object, which is in the format {name: children}
      let categoryMap = [];
        _.forEach(categorySubCategories, function (subCategoryElements, subCategoryName) {
          categoryMap.push({name: subCategoryName, children: subCategoryElements});
        });
      // Now that we've grouped the sub categories, just give the tree it's category name and children
      tree.push({name: categoryName, children: categoryMap});
    });
  };
```